# symfony2 REST, AngularJs access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angularjs, rest, symfony

okay I am desperate. I am using FOSRestBundle and NelmioCorsBundle

I am still getting this error when I am trying to post data by angular from different server:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
http://IP/app_dev.php/api/v1/pages.json. 
No 'Access-    Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin      'http://127.0.0.1:9000' is therefore not allowed access.



Remote Address:IP:80
Request URL:http://IP/app_dev.php/api/v1/pages.json
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,sk;q=0.6,cs;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:192.168.43.195
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:9000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:573
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:Sun, 29 Jun 2014 18:07:54 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
```

I am trying to fix it all day long...

Currently I have:

```
# CORS OPTIONS (add this too)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, content-type"
</IfModule>

nelmio_cors:
    paths:
        '^/api/':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['X-Custom-Auth']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE','OPTIONS']
            max_age: 3600
```

Sending as:

```
            var data = new FormData;
            data.append('title', 'title');
            data.append('body', 'body');

            var request = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: TB+"/app_dev.php/api/v1/pages.json",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+User.getAccessToken(),
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                data: data
            });
```

Any idea what's wrong with it please?

[image: screenshot from 2014-06-29 20 20 01]

Comment: Have you tried to change the nelmio configuration? From the nelmio website: "allow_origin and allow_headers can be set to * to accept any value, the allowed methods however have to be explicitly listed. paths must contain at least one item." So probably you have enabled just the X-Custom-Auth header?

Comment: ```Access-Control-Allow-Origin``` header really doesnt exist in server response

Comment: You have to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the `http://IP/app_dev.php/api/v1/pages.json` server. You could do this in `PHP` or in an `.htaccess`. Also check in your developer tools of the preflight request has succeeded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For me the problem was in network somehow...I think... I was creating a hotspot from mobile... then on laptop (connected to this hotspot) was running the server and from mobile I was trying to access this server.

Because few days later I just setup the router and no more issue with CORS.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem with NelmioCorsBundle, I solved with this settings:

```
nelmio_cors:
    paths:
        '^/api/':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['*']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE','OPTIONS']
            max_age: 3600
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are using chrome you should better get your mind of it working on a localhost ip. a common approach is to reverse proxy localhost into a custom local domain like your-domain.com (for this you would have to use a web server like apache or nginx), reverse proxy all connections to your 127.0.0.1:9000 ip, have an alias in /etc/hosts for 127.0.1.1 your-domain.com and just read the symfony documentation for adding custom headers to your ajax request. i am assuming here you have your ajax routes connected to a controller, a common example would be returning an array of headers as the third parameter

```
return new Response($json, 201, array('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
```

i wouldn't complicate myself much and use 3rd party plugins that i have no control of. hope this helps, it's documented in the symfony cookbook (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html)

Answer (score 1):

`allow_headers: '*'` solved my issue:

```
nelmio_cors:
    paths:
        '^/api/':
            ...
            allow_headers: '*'
            ...
```

For me the error was logged as `Unauthorized header content-type` thrown by NelmioCorsBundle. (I'm Using standard Angular $resource + Symfony + `NelmioCorsBundle` setup)

NelmioCorsBundle by default only allows `'accept'`, `'accept-language'`, `'content-language'` and `'origin'` (see https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle/blob/1.4.0/EventListener/CorsListener.php#L32)

The error is thrown here:
https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle/blob/1.4.0/EventListener/CorsListener.php#L158

--

PS: be aware of the security hole you might open with allowing any origin (`*`)

Answer (score 0):

To access resources on a different server, that server has to declare the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in it's response or it won't work because of browser security policies. It looks like you are not loading Nelmio in your Simfony app.

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        ...
        new Nelmio\CorsBundle\NelmioCorsBundle(),
        ...
    );
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common mistake we do here is that we mismatch the method type in client side and server side. Make sure you have the method type as "POST" in both angularjs and symfony route..!!!